# Can a Post machine have more than one accepting state?

Tags: turing-machines

I was searching through Google and I couldn't find anything.

Can a Post machine have more than one accepting state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the description on Wikipedia, there could be more than one accepting state. The truth is, it doesn't matter. The model with a single accepting state and the model with many accepting states are equivalent. A machine of the former kind is also a machine of the latter kind. In the other direction, starting with a machine with many accepting states, single out one of them as the "real" accepting state, and add transitions from the other states to the chosen accepting state.